# aligning the captions for the side-by-side subfigures

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to put two figures side-by-side in beamer environment. Figures are placed properly using the following lines:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
 ....

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{a.pdf}
  \caption{Figure a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{b.pdf}
  \caption{Figure b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

but the captions are not aligned. The caption for the left figure is nicely placed, but the caption for the right figure shows up a few cm below the figure:

```
|------------------|           |------------------|
|------------------|           |------------------|
|------------------|           |------------------|
    (a) Figure a                   


                                  (b) Figure b
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just use the optional `[t]` argument from `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
%\centering -> This is irrelevant because of the '.5\textwidth' as Mico advised below.
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\columnwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
  \caption{Figure a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
  \caption{Figure b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want the A and B images to be aligned center and the captions to be aligned on the same line?

Comment: I don’t think there is an “official” way to do so. I can think of several hacky ones, like altering the bounding boxes. Although if you haven't found an answer for that, you should really ask a new question and link it here.

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Can you explain what `t` option does? The documentation just says that it defines the `outer-pos` but doesn't explain what this `outer-pos` is.

Comment: @adosar, that very same question is answered under the package documentation FAQ section (page 13, section 2.5, item 1): `[...] use the environment options ‘[t]’ or ‘[b]’ to move the baseline to the top
or bottom rather than the center`. So there you go, it moves the baseline to the desired position.